# Viewing inbox of two different accounts in same folder using alpine

Tags: email, alpine-mail

I have two accounts configured with alpine. In the folder list these accounts are treated as separate and when I want to check mail, I need to go in the Inbox of each account separately.

Is there a way to create a folder that combines the Inbox of all configured accounts so that one only has to open a single folder to view all incoming messages?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the "Incoming Archive Folders" variables. 
For example by putting the following

```
{your_first_email.com}inbox {your_third_email.com}your_archive 
{your_second_email.com}inbox {your_third_email.com}your_archive
```

the inboxes of your first and the second emails archived in the folder "your_archive" or every other folder you like. You should properly put the paths of your folders depending on your email account.

Also please read the Alpine help of "Incoming Archive Folders".